# Broken text in Chrome when using transform-style: preserve-3d; on rotated content with opacity

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transitions, css-transforms

This is how it looks like until the opacity animation is done:

[image]

This is what happens when I try to select the text:
[image]

The issue seems to go away when I remove: `transform-style: preserve-3d;`.

Reproduction online:
https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/z7d0jhk2/22/

Code HTML:

```
<div class="section">
    <h1>Hello man!</h1>
    <h1>Hello man!</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    transition: transform 1000ms ease;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.section.active {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 35deg);
}

h1,
.section {
    transition: opacity 10000ms ease;
}

h1 {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 8em;
}

h1.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Using latest stable Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) for Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3.

I can not reproduce the error in neither Firefox or Safari.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Which version are you using? And on which os?

Comment: Latest stable Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) for Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3

Comment: That's weird... I can not seem to reproduce it in Browserstack with the same version of Chrome either.... But I can in my own computer!

Comment: Strange, the mac version and the windows one should use the same browser-engine. I think it might be a bug. Maybe you should open an issue on the Chromium issue tracker.

Comment: It works correctly even in the Mac version of Browserstack.

Comment: Then try reinstalling your Chrome version. It has to be a problem on your PC.